# how to link javadoc in eclipse help system to code (javadoc location)

Tags: eclipse, birt

some eclipse projects provide their javadoc via http://help.eclipse.org/juno/index.jsp and/or in eclipse' help system (F1).
The problem is that those javadocs aren't linked to code - hovering (or f2) over a class yields

```
Note: The Javadoc for this element could neither be found in the attached source nor the attached Javadoc.
```

So how to link the javadoc from helpsystem to code?

(in my special case i want the birt help linked)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Click on a method which sources are missing and press F3. Then click on `Attach Source...`. Now you have to select a jar file for example which contains the sources of BIRT.

Comment: please read the question- i want to attach javadoc. the javadoc is installed as "feature/plugin" in elipse help (f1) i want this linked with code/jar.

Comment: I really can't find this in your question. But my answer also applies in this case. The sources contains the javadoc you know... If you have installed this as a plug-in there might be also a source-plug-in for birt.

Comment: I think you are mixing two different things here. First the Eclipse-Help which gets extended by the plug-ins you've installed and second the attached javadocs from the libraries you have included in your build path.

Comment: the problem is the javadoc is neither published as jar nor online in a format eclipse can use. U say i have to attach the source (delivered as one zip with 250MB) to each of the birt jars? is this the only way?

Comment: [This page](http://download.eclipse.org/birt/downloads/build.php?build=R-R1-3_7_2-201202141408) provides downloads for the SDK and also the sources. You have to attach the sources only once. To get the help-pages (F1) check the update site, maybe there is such a plug-in available.

Comment: from this page i got the 250mb source file - the only file containing the sources/javadoc for birt.runtime. thi file i attached and it is working. probably you should add this info to your answer: "No it is not possible to link the help. the only way is to attach the sourcecode"